Exactly the same `A < B` expression unexpectedly returns different results in different contexts in MySQL
Today I have encountered an extremely counter-intuitive behavior of < operator in MySQL and I have no idea why.
Specifying exactly the same operands for < gives different results depending on the contexts.
Can anyone explain the reason? This is so counter-intuitive that I even suspect it's a bug of MySQL.
SQL
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE
    t1 (s VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO
    t1 (s)
VALUES
    ('0001/a'),
    ('0001/b'),
    ('0002/a'),
    ('0002/b'),
    ('0003/a'),
    ('0003/b');

SELECT ('/' < ':'); -- => `TRUE`

SELECT ('0002/a' < '0002:'); -- => `TRUE`

SELECT ('0002/b' < '0002:'); -- => `TRUE`

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (s < '0002:'); -- => What will the result be?

Expected Result
+--------+
| s      |
+--------+
| 0001/a |
| 0001/b |
| 0002/a |
| 0002/b |
+--------+

Actual Result
+--------+
| s      |
+--------+
| 0001/a |
| 0001/b |
+--------+

Environment
I use the container version of MySQL with no special configuration:
$ docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql \
  -e 'MYSQL_DATABASE=t' \
  -e 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password' \
  --restart always mysql


Edit 1
I could reproduce the behavior in DB Fiddle:

MySQL 5.7 (NOT reproduced)

MySQL 8.0 (reproduced)


Edit 2
 > show variables like "%collat%"
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value              |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection          | utf8mb3_general_ci |
| collation_database            | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_server              | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| default_collation_for_utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+


I get your expected result.

@user207421 In your environment, SELECT ('/' < ':'); returns 0? In my environment, TRUE (1) is returned.

Try SELECT case when ('/' < ':') then '/<:' else '/>:' end  res1;

The different ordering is possible with different collations (example on db<>fiddle). I'm not overly familiar with database/server admin on MySQL, but at a guess the columns take the database default character set (assuming collation is not explicitly defined in the table) and the string literals take the server default character set, so if these are different it could be why you get different results when comparing to a string literal and comparing to the same string in a table. If you run this: show variables like "%collat%", what results do you get?

@ValNik The result was /<:

@GarethD If you run this: show variables like "%collat%", what results do you get? Please see my edit. I just pasted the result.

In fact, your fiddle has helped me with that, it seems the string literals use the connection default, whereas columns use the database default. If you explicitly set the collation in the query you can get your expected results,e.g. SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (s  COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci < '0002:' ); example on DB Fiddle

@GarethD Thank you. It seems you are correct. collation_connection says collation_connection is important for comparisons of literal strings. For comparisons of strings with column values, collation_connection does not matter and Character Sets, Collations, Unicode says The default MySQL server character set and collation are utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. The problem is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci contradicts with ASCII ordering...

@GarethD If you have time, could you post your comments as an answer? I'll accept it.

As noted in the comments different collations will result in different ordering of characters, so if your comparisons have two different collations you may get two different results.
In your case the database default collation and the connection default collation are different, so when you compare string literals to string literals, the connection default is used, but when you compare a column to string literals the column collation is used which, if not explicitly set when the table is created will be the database default. So you are getting two different results.
This is referenced in the docs for collation_connection (emphasis mine)

The collation of the connection character set. collation_connection is
important for comparisons of literal strings. For comparisons of
strings with column values, collation_connection does not matter
because columns have their own collation, which has a higher collation
precedence (see Section 12.8.4, “Collation Coercibility in
Expressions”).


I think you may have misread the return values for true and false. A successful function call usually returns 0, but in logical operator terms, 0 means false. I get
mysql> SELECT ('/' < ':');
+-------------+
| ('/' < ':') |
+-------------+
|           0 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


Wait, in my environment, 1 is returned. I copied and pasted the expression you wrote.

I ran it on mysql  Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Thank you. Now I also tried DB Fiddle and v5.7 gives the expected result while v8.0 give the unexpected result which is the same as mine.

Maybe it has something to do wiith the default character set/collation. On mine it's utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. Check with SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;

Check with SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database; The result was exactly the same as yours. It turned out this seems the cause: comment.

Wow, this is an interesting 'feature' of mysql. I guess the query should be SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database, @@collation_connection; It seems hazardous to me to have different collations here.
